# How to get filesystem via AWS EC2 dynamic inventory

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-inventory

I found quite a specific issue when setting AWS CloudWatch alarms via ansible using the ec2 dynamic inventory.

I've successfully set up the [aws-script-mon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/mon-scripts.html) to monitor the usage of Disk and RAM usage on my machines.

Also I've managed to set RAM usage alarms with the ansible [ec2_metric_alarm](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_metric_alarm_module.html) module.

The problem I'm facing at the moment is when setting the alarms for disk usage the `Filesystem` dimension parameter is required, but not returned in the [ec2 dynamic inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script) variables.

Some of my machines have filesystem set to `/dev/xvda1` and others have something like: `/dev/disk/by-uuid/abcd123-def4-...`.

My current "solution" is as follows:

```yaml
- name: "Disk > 60% (filesystem by fixed uuid)"
  ec2_metric_alarm:
    state: present
    name: "{{ ec2_tag_Name }}-Disk"
    region: "{{ ec2_region }}"
    dimensions:
      InstanceId: '{{ ec2_id }}'
      MountPath: "/"
      Filesystem: '/dev/disk/by-uuid/abcd123-def4-...'
    namespace: "System/Linux"
    metric: DiskSpaceUtilization
    statistic: Average
    comparison: ">="
    threshold: 60.0
    unit: Percent
    period: 300
    evaluation_periods: 1
    description: Triggered when Disk utilization is more than 60% for 5 minutes
    alarm_actions: ['arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:1234567890:slack']
  when: ec2_tag_Name in ['srv1', 'srv2']

- name: "Disk > 60% (filesystem /dev/xvda1)"
  ec2_metric_alarm:
    state: present
    name: "{{ ec2_tag_Name }}-Disk"
    region: "{{ ec2_region }}"
    dimensions:
      InstanceId: '{{ ec2_id }}'
      MountPath: "/"
      Filesystem: '/dev/xvda1'
    namespace: "System/Linux"
    metric: DiskSpaceUtilization
    statistic: Average
    comparison: ">="
    threshold: 60.0
    unit: Percent
    period: 300
    evaluation_periods: 1
    description: Triggered when Disk utilization is more than 60% for 5 minutes
    alarm_actions: ['arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:1234567890:slack']
  when: ec2_tag_Name not in ['srv1', 'srv2']
```

The only difference between those two tasks is the `Filesystem` dimension and the `when` condition (`in` or `not in`).

Is there any way how to obtain the `Filesystem` value so I can use them as comfortably as let's say `ec2_id`? My biggest concern is that I have to watch filesystem values when creating new machines and handle lists of machines according to that values.

Comment: I'm running in to this same thing with Ansible right now. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Nope, I didn't. Still using the version mentioned in the question=(

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't found a nice solution to this probem, and ended up writing a bash script to generate a YAML file containing UUID variables.

1. Run the script on the remote machine using the [script module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/script_module.html):
   `- script: ../files/get_disk_uuid.sh > /disk_uuid.yml`
2. [Fetch](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/fetch_module.html) the created file from the remote
3. Use the include_vars_module to import the variables from the file. YAML syntax requires hyphens be replaced with underscores in variable names. The disk label 'cloudimg-rootfs' becomes 'cloudimg_rootfs'. Unlabeled disks use the variable names: 'disk0, disk1, disk2...'

Scripts aren't ideal. One day I'd like to write a module that accomplishes this same task.

```
#! /bin/bash
# get_disk_uuid.sh

echo '---'
disk_num=0
for entry in `blkid -o export -s LABEL -s UUID`; do
    if [[ $entry == LABEL* ]];
    then
   label=${entry: 6}
    elif [[ $entry == UUID* ]];
    then
       uuid=${entry: 5}
    fi
    if [ $label ] && [ $uuid ]; then
        printf $label: | tr - _
        printf ' '$uuid'\n'
        label=''
        uuid=''
    elif [ $uuid ]; then
        printf disk$disk_num:
        printf ' '$uuid'\n'
        label=''
        uuid=''
fi
done
```